# MySql Java error: check the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1 when calling PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to call my database, but it keeps getting weirded out and i don't know why.
One time it works, then the next time i change nothing but restart my server it gives this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

I have looked if the id that i am giving in the PreparedStatement is not null, and it is not. (it cannot be either because it is a not null value)
The error gets called on the result set (when the result set gets executed)
Now here is the different things i tried with my mysql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM registration where `registration_id` > ?
SELECT * FROM registration where registration_id > ?
//what used to work:
SELECT * FROM registration where id > ?
```

This is how i execute my query:

```
SQLConnection sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
            Connection conn = sqlConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM registration where `registration_id` > ?";
            try {
                PreparedStatement stmn = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                System.out.println(user.getLastExport());
                stmn.setInt(1, user.getLastExport());
                // execute the query, and get a java resultset
                ResultSet rs = stmn.executeQuery(query);
```

The error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218)
    at houseoftyping.sql.SQLConnection.fillWorkbookWithLastRegistrations(SQLConnection.java:158)
    at houseoftyping.controller.ExcelController.handleDownload(ExcelController.java:106)
    at houseoftyping.controller.ExcelController.doGet(ExcelController.java:51)
    at houseoftyping.controller.ExcelController.doPost(ExcelController.java:197)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what i did wrong:

On the prepared statement i do this:

```
PreparedStatement stmn = conn.prepareStatement(query);
```

So that means my query is loaded inside the prepared statement
Now what i did wrong is i added my query to the result set once again like this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmn.executeQuery(query);
```

**But it needed to be without the query like this:**

```
ResultSet rs = stmn.executeQuery();
```